# I want to create a countdown watch in react, in which user puts in the input, probably in seconds and then it goes down to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is my clock class. I am totally new to react like I started yesterday and still don't have full grasp of state and props. I thought `componentDidMount()` is react function that keeps executing the function which in console I see.It is working now but not perfectly. Its start with decrementing more than it should. Thank you.

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './App';

class Clock extends Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    seconds: 0,
  }
  console.log('this.props',this.props);
}

//
componentWillMount(){
  this.timer(this.props.time);
}

componentDidMount(){
  setInterval(()=> this.timer(this.props.time),1000);
}


timer(time){
  console.log('time in timer', time)
  let count = 0;
time = time - setInterval(count++);
  this.setState({seconds: time});
}


  render(){

    return (
      <div>
      <div className="Clock-seconds">{this.state.seconds} seconds</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

My code in **App.jsx** looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Clock from './Clock';
import './App.css';
import {Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      time: '60',
      newTime: ''
    }
  }

  changeTime(){
    this.setState({time: this.state.newTime});
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className = "App-title">
          Countdown to {this.state.time}
        </div>

        <Clock
          time={this.state.time}
          />

        <Form inline >
          <FormControl
            className="Deadline-input"
            placeholder='new date'
            onChange={event => this.setState({newTime: event.target.value})}
            />
          <Button onClick={() => this.changeTime()}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: State and props are not the same thing!

Comment: state of one component will become prop of another component. I think that is what going on here. I am passing time from parent to child as a props.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with this line: `time = time - setInterval(count++);`

I'm not quite sure what that's supposed to do, but here's how I would approach it:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    seconds: null, // you'll want to test for null
    timerID: null // this will capture the timer ID so you can clear it. Otherwise every time you navigate away and back to this component, it will create a new timer.
  }
  console.log('this.props',this.props);
}

componentWillMount(){
  //this.timer(this.props.time); // get rid of this altogether, it's not needed and you generally should avoid willMount in favor of didMount
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setTimer();
  //setInterval(()=> this.timer(this.props.time),1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.state.timerID);
}

  setTimer() {
    const {time} = this.props;

    // set state with props if it isn't defined yet
    if (this.state.seconds === null) this.setState({seconds: time});

    // clear existing timer if there is one, to avoid memory leaks
    if (this.state && this.state.timerID) clearInterval(this.state.timerID);

    // define the function that will run each 1 sec
    const tick = () => {
      this.setState({
        seconds: this.state.seconds--
      });
    };

    // set the interval and capture the ID so you can clear it later
    const id = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    this.setState({timerID: id});
  }
```

Note, I haven't tested this code but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for response, for some reason it is not ticking. I see seconds and but it not updating nor going down. I will figure out something.